# Creating responsive nav that aligns to the right on mobile but snaps to the center on larger screens

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a `nav` with a logo and links. I want the logo to always remain in the same position, vertically centered on the left, but I want the link items to change depending on the screen size.

1. On small screens, I want a small font size with the links aligned to the right
   2.On medium screens, I want a medium font size with the links aligned in the center
2. On large screens, I want a larger font size with the links aligned in the center

Ideally, I want the changes to happen whenever the text is right about to hit the logo.

[Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZZilX1yMATsTC_nVfyq4Zab3K33nTWh/view?usp=sharing) to what I'm picturing.

Comment: Great! So what have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions. I recommend you to add some piece of code. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called breakpoints - it changes CSS styling when viewport size changes. The syntax looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

You can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to adjust font size and positioning based on screen size.  `@media (max-width 600px) {
[your nav name] a { font-size: .7rem; float: right; }}` for example.  Adjust for different screens accordingly.